# Responsive centered Popup that fits his Content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying for the last couple hours to get a responsive Box that is centered and automatically shrinks to his contents.

I can't figure out how to get it to work.

I'm using this:

```
display: inline-block;
```

This way I get it to fit his contents and I align my popup in the center with :

```
text-align: center;
```

But I can't figure out how to get it to be responsive.

EDITED :

Sorry that the Code was missing! 
Here it is :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        .ModalWrapper {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .ModalPopup {
            background: #ffffff;
            border-radius: 5px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: solid thin #19b4b5;
        }
        .ModalTop {
            text-align: center !important;
            width: 100%;
            height: 30%;
            min-height: 30%;
            padding-top: 5%;
            padding-bottom: 5%;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            background-color: #19b4b5;
        }
        .ModalContent {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div class="ModalWrapper">
        <div class="ModalPopup">
            <div class="ModalTop">Your Post</div>
            <div class="ModalContent">
                <div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/" data-show-text="true">
                    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"></blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is not optimized yet and I´m a total newbie to web development.

Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Comment: You need to explain better what you mean by _get it to be responsive_

Comment: I mean the size of the popup.

Comment: I want it to have different sizes on different resolutions.  For example on Phones I want it to be basically 90% of the width but on laptops for example it should be 40%.

Comment: We can't see any popup, no html and just 2 lines of CSS, how do you expect anyone to be able to make any reasonable answer with that?

Comment: Bootstrap is an easy way to add responsiveness: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Sorry I couldn´t post the code because I wasn´t at home. 
I edited the inital post now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap to add responsiveness.  It's a little cumbersome with the HTML but it works well and is easy to use.  Download Bootstrap here:

http://getbootstrap.com/

Then implement it by wrapping your pop-up inside a "row" div:

`<div class="row">`

and another div that specifies the size, for example:

`<div class="col-md-4">`

Different sizes and layouts of grids will allow you flexibility to determine how responsive you want it to be.

You can see many examples of how to use Bootstrap's grids here:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/